# Can't get WCF service to send XML Document to BizTalk Receive Location

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I'm new to BizTalk and WCF services and am trying to figure out how to use a WCF service to deliver XML data to Biztalk. I think I'm close but when I call the WCF service operation, the operation executes successfully but does not appear to generate any kind of a message in Biztalk. Am I wrong in assuming that simply calling an operation is enough to trigger a message to BizTalk?

Below is my code and some details about my BizTalk configuration:

WCF service:

```
public interface IService1
{
       [OperationContract, XmlSerializerFormat]
       XmlDocument GetXMLDocument(string sourceXML);
}

public class Service1 : IService1  
{  
    public XmlDocument GetXMLDocument(string sourceXML)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(sourceXML);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Calling application (button click calls the service):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();     
        doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Patients", "test"));
        SendDoc(doc);             
}

protected void SendDoc(XmlDocument doc)
{
      //use a Service Client Object to call the service   
      objServiceClientobjService.GetXMLDocument(doc.OuterXml);      
}
```

BizTalk configuration:

Receive Port:

- Port type: One-Way

Receive Location:

- Type: WCF-Custom with basicHTTP binding
- Endpoint Address is the same as the IIS hosted WCF Service
- Receive Pipeline Type: XMLReceive

Comment: you implemented the service in IIS. not in BizTalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is not correct. There is no link between your WCF service and BizTalk. If you want to receive xml in BizTalk then you need to expose either an Orchestration or Xml Schema as WCF service using BizTalk WCF Web Service Publishing Wizard. This gets installed with BizTalk. Please see link for more details: [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226547.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I always use, is to expose an endpoint. Take a look at [this example](http://www.codit.eu/blog/2010/08/11/hosting-wcf-http-receive-location-inside-biztalk-without-using-iis/):